# Rendering array using Ember {{each}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js

A route `/numbers` has the JavaScript:

```
// app/routes/numbers.js
// ...
numbers: [1,2,3,4,5],
// ...
```

and in the route's template:

```
<!-- app/templates/numbers.hbs -->
{{#each numbers as |n|}}
  <p>{{n}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

---

When I view the `/numbers` route, nothing is rendered inside the `{{each}}` helper. Why not?

Comment: Note that any variables you want be accessed in templates, should be defined in controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access properties that you set in the route in the template. If you want to access the numbers array in the template, then you will need to set it in the controller using `setupController`.

The "Ember way" to pass data to templates is to get the data in the route's `model` hook, then set it on the controller in `setupController`

In your route, do this:

```
model: function(params, transition) {
  return this.get('numbers');
},

setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model);
}
```

then in your template, instead of accessing the numbers array, use `model`

```
{{#each model as |n|}}
  <p>{{n}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

for more information read this: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/

Comment: setupController isn't necessary. But if you want setup another property to the controller. you use it. `controller.set("number",model);`